# Xamarin - Call System.IDisposable.Disposeon object created before all references to it are out of scope

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am quite new to Xamarin and C# (however, I do know C++ and Java, so I have been doing fine with the latter so far). I ran into a warning when creating an `IOnCheckedChangedListener` for a checkbox that I am using in my (Android-)app.

So far, I have created a simple class `OnCheckedChangedListener` which inherits from `Java.lang.Object` and implements `IOnCheckedChangeListener`. Naturally, the method `OnCheckedChanged()` has also been implemeneted.

I have set the listener by using

```
OnCheckedChangedListener listener = new OnCheckedChangedListener();
checkBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Everything works fine so far, but I get the warning *"Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by 'new OnCheckedChangedListener()' before all references to it are out of scope."*

I can remove this warning by either calling `listener.Dispose()` after setting the listener or by wrapping the entire thing (thing as in the creating of the listener and setting it in the checkbox) into a `using` block. This gets rid of the warning, but results in a runtime-error whenever the listener would have been called (I assume this is because I have effectively deleted the listener but the program still tried to call it).

According to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57287/is-there-ever-a-need-to-call-explicitly-call-dispose-on-an-object-in-ios), there is no need to actually call `Dispose()` but I would really like to get rid of the warning. Is there a good way to get rid of it (optimally without telling the compiler to simply ignore it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something when user check or uncheck the checkbox, you could  register for the RadioGroup's CheckedChange event like the following

```
checkBox.CheckedChange += OnCheckedChange;
```

```
private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, RadioGroup.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
{
        //include your code logic here
}
```

Or you could use lambda directly

```
checkBox.CheckedChange += (s, e) =>
{
    //include your logic here
    //s = sender (checkbox)
    //e = RadioGroup.CheckedChangeEventArgs
};
```

Comment: Just asking, doesn't it do the same in behind as the code in the question?

Comment: They are different , the above code is registering event , and in your question , you added a listener .

Comment: Of course they have the same function . But the above is  easier .

Comment: This is not my question, I am just commenting. I see that those are different, but I still say the same - if you subscribe to event it will generate a listener while the app is running as that is the only way to get the callback in Android and then I don't see how this helps to resolve the problem. Again just asking, I might be wrong.